# Get text before <br/> python/bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data from one web page. There are newlines and `<br/>` tags in the tag text. I want to get only the telephone number on the beginning of the tag. Will you give me an advice how to get only the number?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<td>
    +421 48/471 78 14



    <br />
    <em>(bowling)</em>
</td>
```

Is there a way in beautifulsoup to get a text in a tag, but only that text, which is not surrounded by other tags? And the second thing: to get rid of text newlines and html newlines?

I use BS4.

The output would be: '+421 48/471 78 14'

Have you any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
html="""
<td>
    +421 48/471 78 14



    <br />
    <em>(bowling)</em>
</td>
"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find("td").contents[0].strip() 
+421 48/471 78 14

print soup.find("td").next_element.strip()
+421 48/471 78 14
```

`soup.find("td").contents[0].strip()` finds the contents of the `tag` which we get the first element of and  remove all the `\n` newline chars with `str.strip()`.

And from the docs [next_element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element):

*The .next_element attribute of a string or tag points to whatever was parsed immediately afterwards*

Answer (score 1):

Does it work for you?

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> str = str.replace("\n", "") # get rid of newlines
>>> str = "<td>   +421 48/471 78 14    <br /><em>(bowling)</em></td>"
>>> for item in soup.td.children:
...   phone = item # first item is the phone number
...   break
... 
>>> phone
u'   +421 48/471 78 14    '
>>> phone.strip()
u'+421 48/471 78 14'
>>>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. The problem is probably that in your string there are spaces, but my string contains newlines as in the code above (before <br /> tag.

Comment: then you can get rid of the newlines : str = str.replace("\n", "")

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to get rid of  tag using `decompose()` [method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose)
(removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '''
<td>
    +421 48/471 78 14



    <br />
    <em>(bowling)</em>
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, 'html.parser')
em = soup.select_one('em').decompose()

phone = soup.select_one('td').text.strip()
print(phone)
```

Output:

```
+421 48/471 78 14
```