# How to parse into span class tag using bs4 python3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse into the contents:

```
<span class="postbody">here is some text
```

However, I am not sure how I can do this. The following is a snippet of code that loads every *span with class "postbody"*

```
post_bodies = soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "postbody"})
```

After loading this, how can I parse so I can extract "here is some text? I am thinking I need to use regex but I am quite confused on how to go about it. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

**EDIT: Complete tag**

```
<span class="postbody">here is some text
<br/>
<br/>
RJ<br/>_________________<br/>user (blalah Admin)
<br/>
some random text.</span>
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete DOM and code snippet? If `span` has child elements with their own text contents, that might change the result. Otherwise, just `[elem.text for elem in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "postbody"})]` should be sufficient.

Comment: @ggorlen I have made an edit to the OP. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yep. Those `br` tags make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text before <br/> python/bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25476316/get-text-before-br-python-bs4)

Comment: `elem = soup.find("span", {"class" : "postbody"}).next_element` from the above link should do the trick. You can `.strip()` the newlines if needed. Let me know if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ggorlen That did the trick! Thank you so much!